# Multi select textbox and it's selected portion should be rearrage with drag-drop

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am creating one page which provides two input  textbox for Audio codec and video codec.
The input textbox is multi select textbox like On focus -it will display list of codecs and we can selecting each from the list 
Now my problem is When i select for audio codec then video codec doesnot work i.e. at a time only one input box is working
and it does not allow to rearrange the selected codecs priority .

i am using HTML5 and javascript for it and on submit button click - i am using python code views.py

Any kind of help is appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-4 tlabel trunktitle"> 
Audio Codecs
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7 add_other trunkdata"> 
     <select class="form-control input-sm" name="audio_codecs" id="audio_codecs" style="height:100%;"  multiple>
    {% for tr in audiocodec_list %}
    <option value="{{ tr.audio_codec_id }}"> {{ tr.audio_codec }}           </option>                        
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <script>                                                                                                
                                          if(!document.getElementById('test')) {
                                            $('#audio_codecs').popover({content:"Select the Audio Codecs.",placement:"top"});           
                                            $('#audio_codecs').popover('show'); 
    return false;
  } 
                                          $('#audio_codecs').popover('hide');   
});  

</script>   
</div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 tlabel trunktitle"> 
   Video Codecs
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-7 add_other trunkdata"> 
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="video_codecs" id="video_codecs" style="height:100%;"  multiple>
    {% for tr in videocodec_list %}
    <option value="{{ tr.video_codec_id|add:audiocodec_count }}"> {{ tr.video_codec }} </option>                         
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<script>    
    var ms = $('#video_codecs').magicSuggest({});                                           
$('.ms-sel-ctn').sortable();    

                                        $(ms).on('selectionchange', function(e,m) {
                                          if(!document.getElementById('test')) {
                                            $('#video_codecs').popover({content:"Select the Video Codecs.",placement:"top"});           
                                            $('#video_codecs').popover('show');                                         return false;
  } 
                                          $('#video_codecs').popover('hide');   
});  

</script>   
</div>
     </div>


</div>
```

Comment: can you put a demo , or little code for help you?

Comment: code is given above. in my template, i am using script for multiselectbut how to rearrange is my problem